# foreach and hide/show multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have little problem with jQuery.

I have multiple DIVs like this:

```
<input id="amount_sell" onkeyup="cal_sell()" value="" placeholder="Amount" type="text">

<div id="all">
    <ul>
        <li id="USD">...</li>
        <li id="USD">...</li>
        <li id="USD">...</li>
        <li id="EUR">...</li>
        <li id="EUR">...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here my jQuery code:

```
var convert = new Array();
convert["USD"] = 1;
convert["EUR"] = 1.372;

function cal_sell() {
    var currency = $('#currency').val();

    for (key in convert) {
        if(key == currency) {
            $('#all #'+currency).each(function(index, item){    
                $(item).show();
            });
        } else {
            $('#all #'+currency).each(function(index, item){    
                $(item).hide();
            }); 
        }
    }   
}
```

I want when someone select USD, there only USD ID that will be showed, if I select EUR all  `<li>` with `id=USD` will hide and display EUR `<li>` ...

But when I use this one, when I select EUR all `<li>` of EUR will be hide, and same for USD.

Please help me to fix this problem, thank you.

Comment: `id`s are meant to be unique. Yours are not.

Comment: Same when i use class ... i looking for way to make it work

Comment: your code is incomplete, we can't help you this way

Comment: It's complete now, i just modified it

Comment: I agree with @Andy will be good if you use a class instead of id here for id="USD" and id="EUR". By default if you use ID it will get only the first id combination, in your case 1st and 4th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part of code:

```
 $('#all #'+currency).each(function(index, item){    
    $(item).hide();
    });
```

by:

```
 $('#all #'+key).each(function(index, item){    
    $(item).hide();
    });
```

You just forgot to change `currency` by `key` variable in this part of code.

Comment: I accepted the answer :) i cant up vote, i am new :)

Answer (score 1):

Make it more simple:

```
 <div id="all">
 <ul>
    <li class="USD">...</li>
    <li class="USD">...</li>
    <li class="USD">...</li>
    <li class="EUR">...</li>
    <li class="EUR">...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Just hide all the items and show the current selection:

```
function cal_sell() {
    var currency = $('#currency').val();
    $('#all li').hide();
    $('#all li.'+currency).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `select` it easier to do it this way. I've opted for data attributes instead of classes.

**HTML**

```
<li data-id="USD">USD</li>
<li data-id="USD">USD</li>
<li data-id="USD">USD</li>
<li data-id="EUR">EUR</li>
<li data-id="EUR">EUR</li>
```

**JS**

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
  var option = $('select option:selected').val();
  $('li').show();
  $('li[data-id!="' + option + '"]').hide();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LP4w/13/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need a for each with a multiple jQuery selector.
You can use directly:

```
 $("#all #" + currency).hide() or show()
```

Second the each item value is already a jQuery wrapped DOM element, so you can use

```
item.show()
item.hide();
```

And finally you are showing and hiding the same element with the same class. You need to use the not selector.

So all will be:

```
for (key in convert) {
    if(key == currency) {
        $('#all #'+currency).show()
    } else {
        $('#all li:not(#'+currency+')').hide();
    }
}
```